# Fail to Facebook api request using URLConnection in JAVA

Tags: java, facebook, access-token, urlconnection

I am trying to developing Facebook API using Java.

It is success to get access_token from facebook as flow.

```
        String access_token_url = targetURI +
                "client_id=" + appId +
                "&client_secret=" + appSecret +
                "&code=" + code +
                "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI; // 호출되지 않음

        URL url = new URL (access_token_url);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
        String accessTokenStr="";

        while ((accessTokenStr=in.readLine()) != null) {                
            int endPnt = accessTokenStr.indexOf("&");
            access_token = accessTokenStr.substring(13, endPnt);
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@ access_token = " + access_token);
        }
        in.close();
```

This case(see the below source) occurred exception (code: 400) for get the own information using above access_token.

```
        String access_userInfo_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" + "access_token=" + access_token;

        System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@ access_userInfo_url==============" + access_userInfo_url); 

        URL url = new URL (access_userInfo_url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        //urlConn.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        //urlConn.setReadTimeout(1000);
        //urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(access_userInfo_url.length()));              

        String userInfoStr="";          
        while ((userInfoStr=input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@ userInfoStr = " + userInfoStr);   
        }

        input.close();
```

Recieved excetion message as flow.

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAC7APV7WpoBAHVfr2ChZAK4wVrQZCjNSbro3LgABvoFSMMSHmiloS5m95z3DCeNsZBoOHFsClrgBVIqZCCwg8JZCK3Xd0fq6uyu8GJbYNENFQCDKz25IsguBSXuReapPvZA3ZC3BuJVLPwpZAfVCZCqFW0wj6o6ZA6nXO5JzCutZBAum2cJQjiBwctFkzxWqxinz8ZD
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at biztopia.facebook.web.FacebookController.requestUserInfo(FacebookController.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

~
~
~
~

I'm confused that it is success when request on web-browser(explorer) as "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=Token value".

Please help me who have solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
public String getUserInfo(String access_token) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
    try {
        String connection = connectionGet("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + access_token, "");
        return connection;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}


public static String connectionGet(String url, String parameter) throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {

    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection request1 = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
    request1.setRequestMethod("GET");
    request1.connect();
    String responseBody = convertStreamToString(request1.getInputStream());
    return responseBody;
}

  private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The necessary imports will be:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.ProtocolException;
 import java.net.URL;
```

Comment: Thank's Jhanvi! I was tried to your solutions, unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~

Comment: Paste this on your browser : https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAAC7APV7WpoBAHVfr2ChZAK4wVrQZCjNSbro3LgABvoFSMMSHmiloS5m95z3DCeNsZBoOHFsClrgBVIqZCCwg8JZCK3Xd0fq6uyu8GJbYNENFQCDKz25IsguBSXuReapPvZA3ZC3BuJVLPwpZAfVCZCqFW0wj6o6ZA6nXO5JzCutZBAum2cJQjiBwctFkzxWqxinz8ZD  .Are you getting anything?

Comment: Performing success! Returned my infoamtion file formed JSON. That is my confused.

Comment: Did you tried my exact code?? Because i am using the same and it works. ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions.
That is append appsecret_proof parameter at call API as "http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token={access_token value}$appsecret_proof={appsecret_proof value}.

If you are no want append appsecret_proof parameter then you can change set to no use appsecret_proof paameter on your app management site.
The management site menu is setting>advanced>Require AppSecret Proof for Server API calls -> set to disabled.